# Clarification of actions on netbeans Github

Tags: git, netbeans

I would just like a little clarification for I seem to be stuck in an endless loop.

I'm getting ready to get new code that was pushed to the remote branch that I'm working on. I commit my work and decide to pull. It tells me that a Merge Commit Needed. I click the merge button. Then it asks to resolve the conflicts. I select resolve and depending on what I see I choose to select my code or both on each file that has a conflict.

Now after saving I'm back to the same location that I started. I try to pull and I get the same problem. What step am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in "[Git in netbeans - resolving conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10941711/6309)", once you have right click the files, Git>Resolve Conflicts, you would still need to commit.

Only after committing would a pull (with its merge) be fully done.

Comment: When I try to commit again it says that there are no files to be committed.

Comment: @Tolure did you add first your modifications? (the ones done when resolving the merge conflicts)